# Apache: subdomain, file visibility

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I have a subdomain:

my.mydomain.com

my .conf file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my/

    <Directory /var/www/html/my/ >
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Question:

If I go to h**p://my.mydomain.com/myfile.txt I see the file.  That's good.

If I go to h**p://mydomain.com/my/myfile.txt I see the file as well.

How can I prevent the 2nd option from not seeing the file, while allowing the 1st option to see it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a default `<VirtualHost>` which catches any hostname which hasn't been set up explicitly.

See [An In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html) for details.

Comment: This is perfect reading for my learning process -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want the /my/ to be available under the parent domain, you need to give your subdomain *VirtualHost* a completely separate *DocumentRoot*. I take it that **/var/www/html/** is the *DocumentRoot* for the parent *VirtualHost*? If so, try using something like **/var/www/my/** as the subdomain *DocumentRoot*.